# Some indicators are missing when unlocking the screen

Tags: unity, indicator, lock-screen, system-tray

It happened on my old PC and it still happens with the new one, with a fresh Ubuntu 12.10 installation (Unity).
When returning from a screen lock (I couldn't say if it can be replicated in other ways), some indicators are missing: pidgin, thunderbird (with firetray extension), jdownloader...

I don't know whether those indicators have something wrong regarding unity's tray or something related with global menu is cutting out a certain size of left edge of a long tray, whatever it contains.

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to update to the new gnome-screensaver with apt. the new Version is 3.6.0. and fixes some broken links with the lock screen!

Here is the Changelog - i think this might help! It has been released  four days ago!

---

> gnome-screensaver (3.6.0-0ubuntu2.1) quantal-security; urgency=low
>
> - SECURITY UPDATE: broken screen locking with Unity desktop (LP: #1120126)
>
>   - debian/patches/19_autostart_in_unity.patch: change AutostartCondition
>       so gnome-screensaver gets started properly in the Unity session also.
>   - CVE-2013-1050  -- Marc Deslauriers    Sat, 09 Feb 2013 09:44:56 
>       -0500
>
> ** Changed in: gnome-screensaver (Ubuntu Quantal)
>          Status: Confirmed => Fix Released

Comment: I'm already running that version.